# Minimal height of svg in html

Tags: html, svg

I found out that low (height < 16px) SVGs are placed in HTML with a strange vertical offset (similar but not identical behavior across browsers). First 2 examples at http://plnkr.co/edit/ekdIzBtXKMh3aRHpLus5?p=preview demonstrate the situation:

Bad - line w/ offset:

```
<div style="height: 1px; width: 100%;">
    <svg width="100%" height="1px">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-width="1"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

vs. Good - line w/o offset (1px below border):

```
<div style="height: 1px; width: 100%;">
    <svg width="100%" height="16px">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-width="1"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Is anyone aware of the real (e.g. specs-based) explanation of this? I would like to be able to have 1px high (line) SVG placed correctly. Is there a way to be 100% sure?

Thanks anyone for hints,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/iwdXTMS66EAjJWb2vcHO?p=preview
Fixed... ;)

```
svg{display:block;}
```

to get rid of inline elements default margins